# Question about step in proof of Schauder's theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

The statement is the following: Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces and $T:X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous linear operator. Then is $T'$ compact iff $T$ is compact.
I have already understood the implication $T$ is compact $ \Rightarrow $ $T'$ is compact.
But the other implication is somewhat more strange to me: Let $T'$ be compact, then $T''$ is compact from what was shown earlier. Then $T''i_x$ is also compact ( This is clear because the canonical map $i_X:X \rightarrow X''$ is linear and continuous and therefore is $T''i_X$ also compact). Since we have $T''i_X=i_YT$ we know that $i_YT$ is compact. Now I do not unerstand the following:

Since $Y$ is closed in $Y''$(why is this true?), is $T$ also compact(why is this true?)

Comment: 1. $Y$ is closed in $Y''$ because $Y$ is complete.  2. The image of the unit ball of $X$ under $T$ is the same as the image of the unit ball of $X$ under $T''$.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith thank you. I know that complete spaces must be closed, but $Y$ is not an actual subset(or subspace) of $Y''$. I guess we are talking here about the question whether $i_Y(Y)$ is closed or not, right? But how do we know that $i_Y(Y)$ is still complete? 2.) Actually, I do not get it. What does compactness have to do with the image of some unit ball?

Comment: Actually, I think the first one could be true because $i_Y$ is an isometry. But I am still struggeling with your second answer.

Comment: The definition I use of compact is that it maps the unit ball to a pre-compact set.  (I see on wikipedia that they use "bounded" instead of unit ball, but it is an equivalent definition.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embedding in the second dual [is isometric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442197/weakly-compact-implies-bounded-in-norm/442198#442198), in particular it is bounded below. [Hence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294895/operatornameranget-is-a-closed-subspace?lq=1) $\operatorname{Range}(i_Y)$ is closed in $Y^{**}$.

Since $i_YT$ is compact then $K:=i_Y(T(B_X))$ is compact. Since $i_Y$ is an isometry, then so does $j:i_Y(Y)\to Y: i_Y(y)\mapsto y$ and what is more $ji_Y=1_Y$. Since $j$ is an isometry then $j(K)$ is compact too, but $j(K)=j(i_Y(T(B_X)))=T(B_X)$. Thus $T(B_X)$ is compact, so $T$ is compact.